# How to filter app bundle ids from list of string in ruby

Tags: ruby, url

I have a list of strings that are either urls, domains, and app bundle IDs I want a ruby code or either regular expression that can filter out app bundle IDs from the list of strings. Here is an example list

```
com.fox.fts.android
com.offerup 
com.twitchyfinger.google.minilegend 
com.ste.android.schnopsnfree 
com.jakob.pushdice 
com.effective.start.solitaire 
com.zm.colorstack3d 
com.cam.scanner.camerascanner.document.scanner 
com.astarsoftware.euchre 
com.zumba.game.free.puzzle.marble 
com.tripledot.solitairescapes 
com.crazylabs.tie.dye.art 
com.casualino.vipspades 
com.quok.puzzleunscrew 
com.holagogames.softris
```

I have searched and found that app bundle IDs are the reverse of the domain if I have google.com then the app bundle IDs is com.google.myapp I have then checked that the string starts with com. will be app bundle ids but I am not sure if other than the .com domain also has app bundle ids.

Comment: App bundle ids and domains or web presence of the same app is a convention and not mandatory i think.

Comment: When you find a string like `com.example.foo` how do you decide if it is a domain, an app ID, neither, or both?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure these are *required* to begin with `com`, they could start with `eu` or various country codes. `com` is merely tradition.